# (//.) Expression in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this little problem in getting an XPATH expression result !

Let's say i have this little XML file :

```
<bookstore>
 <book>
  <title lang="en">Learning Java</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
 </book>

 <book>
  <title lang="en">Learning Xpath</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

What will be the result of :

```
//book[//.='Lear']
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to find, all books that have a title with 'Lear' in it?

Comment: As your root element is `/bookstore`, `/book` will return no elements

Answer (score 1):

> What will be the result of :
>
> `//book[//.='Lear']`

You can always dump XML sample and xpath expression in an xpath tester and see the result by yourself (f.e using http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html, or whatever you like). For the above xpath and XML sample, the result will be nothing. Given that particular XML input, the above xpath expression is the same as `//book[false()]`. The predicate (content of `[]`) evaluate to `false` because there is no element containing exact string `"Lear"`.

> "But can you tell me what's useful about the dot after the double slash symbol ?"

To answer that comment, see the following break-down :

- `//` : Abbreviated syntax for `descendant-or-self` axis.
- `.` : Reference current context node.
- `//.` : You can read this as *find any node anywhere in the XML document*. That can also be expressed as `//self::node()`. Note that `//` starts searching from the root element, it doesn't care about current `book` element being the context.

Comment: Then what could be the difference between `//*` and `//.`?

Comment: @revo `//*` only returns *descendant **elements*** (excluding text nodes and current node), while `//.` returns *descendant **and self nodes***. F.e try `//book[1]//*` vs `//book[1]//.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find all books containing title with 'Lear', try this:

```
//book[contains(title,'Lear')]
```

Comment: Thanks, But can you tell me what's useful about the dot after the double slash symbol ?

Answer (score 0):

`//book` selects all `book` elements that are descendants of the **current context** (in your case that would be the root element).

`[]` indicates a condition to apply to the selection, so in essence you will be filtering `book` elements.

Inside the square brackets `[]` the **current context** becomes `book` so `//` means any descendant of book. `.` simply denotes the element itself which is used here to apply the `=` operator to. So `//` means all descendants, `//.` means "what follows applies to the element which is any descendant`.

Comment: "*...so `//` means any descendant of `book`*". This part is wrong. It is true for `.//` but not `//`. f.e try `//book[//title='Learning Java']`, that will return both `book` elements